# Chrome meta viewport-fit=cover on an android with display cutouts

Tags: css, display-cutouts

It appears that latest Chrome on Android 9 "Pie" does not behave as Safari on iPhone X when using the `viewport-fit=cover`. Safari stretches the content full screen, into the cutouts area while Chrome does not (see screenshot of Huawei Y6 below) **Is this standard behavior on Android or a transitional phase to a Safari like behavior?**

On iPhoneX the code below makes the content stretch edge to edge also into the cutouts area. Then, you compensate for the notch "eating" into the actual content by using the CSS safe area constants to apply margin, padding etc:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}
</style>
```

On latest Chrome on Adroid 9 Pie the area in the "horns", next to the notch (the actual cutouts) is always "safe" and has either the default background color of the browser chrome (off-white) or whatever you define in the `<meta name="theme-color">` tag. The CSS safe area constants do nothing cuz... there is nothing to safeguard against.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue and all documentation that I find points out that this code is correct. But it didn't work in the 4 Android devices that I used to tested.

Comment: try margin-top instead.